# How to measure the lifetime of a Javascript Object? Can we measure AJAX object lifetime in the same way?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox, instrumentation

I want to measure the Object lifetime for Javascript and AJAX objects. What infrastructure is needed to do so? Are there any tools available that can be useful. Microsoft Research has this Technical Report http://www.msr-waypoint.com/en-us/um/people/livshits/papers/tr/jsmeter_tr.pdf in which they instrument the Internet Explorer Source to get approximate Javascript lifetime. Can a dynamic binary instrumentation tool like PIN be of any use in case for Mozilla Firefox? And where exactly the instrumentation hooks should be added to get details about object lifetime.

EDIT: I know the exact lifetime cannot be known as the object is dead the moment it has no references pointing to it. Even an over approximation of the lifetime (When the object is actually collected by the Garbage collector) is fine for this study.

Comment: It's difficult to measure the "lifetime" of a javascript object because the second it "dies" is when no variables are referencing it and the garbage collection picks it up. If you're trying to measure how long a script or ajax runs or something, you can create a Date object at the start of the request and another Date object at the end, and measure the seconds between the two.

Comment: Sorry, I missed to add that detail. Thanks for pointing it out.
I know the exact lifetime cannot be known as the object is dead the moment it has no references pointing to it. Even an over approximation of the lifetime (When the object is actually collected by the Garbage collector) is fine for this study. 
And actually I want to measure lifetime of Javascript objects in real web sites, so modifying the real website scripts is not an option. :(

Comment: The only thing I can think is create your own Javascript interpreter, or create a custom version of Firefox that reports what you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions